# AWS - Assign an Elastic IP to a ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip, amazon-elb

Is it possible to assign an Elastic IP to a Load Balancer?

Answer (score 12):

No it is not. Elastic Load Balancers do not have a fixed IP address - it is possible that a single ELB is actually multiple appliances, so as to overcome the bottleneck that would otherwise occur with very high load (i.e. if all connections were passing through a single ELB). ELBs will scale up by increasing their number. As such, it is recommended that you use the DNS address instead, as this can internally be mapped to the IP of any ELB appliance serving your requests (much like round robin DNS). Typically, you will use a CNAME to map the provided DNS value to a subdomain (e.g. www) of your domain.

For a more detailed overview of the functioning of ELBs see [this article](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/07/elastic-in-elastic-load-balancing-elb.html).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to assign an Elastic IP Address to an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB).

However, it may be possible to do what you are trying to accomplish using different AWS features if you explain what you thought this would be a solution for.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019 it is possible to have **static IP** for Load Balancer:

> Using a Network Load Balancer instead of a Classic Load Balancer has
> the following benefits:
>
> - Support for static IP addresses for the load balancer. You can also
>   assign one Elastic IP address per subnet enabled for the load
>   balancer.